# Error with R.java class, layout no found but present in R.java

Tags: java, android, eclipse

Well, first I'm sorry but my english is not very good because I'm French...
I work on Eclipse on an android project (pong)
So, I've a problem with an activity, when I write :  setContentView(R.layout.menu);
I have an error who say : menu cannot be resolved or is not a field
The fact is... This is a file !  I went to the R.java and I see it, but the error don't disappear. (I have alredy clean and build the project many times, it still don't work)
I have took some screens ;-)

http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/4/erreurmenupong1.png/  (In the Menu.java)
http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/62/erreurmenupong2.png/  (In the R.java)

Comment: Just build your project, after that the exception may leave. If don't, then make sure this `menu` variable is configured in the res/layout folder.

Comment: Please copy the relevant sections of code into your post. One quick check - are you importing 'R' or is it in the same package.

Comment: I have already clean it (I just edit my post).  And in the layout folder, there is menu.xml.  But before I had changed the layout size it don't work. Then , I remade the size as it was when it worked, but nothing...

Comment: Try deleting your R.java folder, and it will generate itself after few seconds. This might solve the problem. Otherwise try renaming your xml to something else and see if that works.

Comment: Please post import statements of `Menu.java`. I guess you are importing wrong `R` file.

Comment: It's good guys, I just have delete the    import android.R;  and the error is visibly fixed !  Thanks all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delete "android.R" from your imports.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same exact problem. I solved it buy making a new work space and importing all my android projects over there.

Comment: This seems a little extreme. Plus, read the [last comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15209746/error-with-r-java-class-layout-no-found-but-present-in-r-java#comment21436019_15209746), the OP found their issue.

Comment: That's good to hear. Just to note: this also once happened to me when I changed my API level to above 11 from the manifest.